# CHECK failed while writing custom loss layer in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, caffe, loss, glog

I get the following error while running a test case for a custom built loss function in `caffe`. This loss function uses Reshape layer on the `bottom` blob to this layer (This is mentioned in the `LayerSetUp()` method of the Custom loss function.

Error:

```
F0704 01:49:54.075613 16977 blob.cpp:145] Check failed: diff_ 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f627a1965cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f627a198433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f627a19615b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f627a198e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f62754dd96b  caffe::Blob<>::mutable_cpu_diff()
    @           0x500e8a  caffe::CustomLossLayerTest_TestRead_Test<>::TestBody()
    @           0x940693  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x939caa  testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x939df8  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x939ed5  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x93b1af  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x93b4d3  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x46f5fd  main
    @     0x7f6274811830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x477229  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Makefile:532: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Aborted (core dumped)
```

What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: @Shai I had forgotten to setup (call `SetUp` method) of one of the Reshape layer which I was using internally and that was the problem. There is no such error now.

Comment: @Shai I had one more small doubt, I've added a softmax layer within my custom layer which takes in input part of `bottom[0]` blob. I have allotted memory to this blob using `new` operator. Should I be worried about `free`ing the memory and where exactly should I delete this memory allocation ?

Comment: interesting question. But I have no clue what your code looks like... Seems like a new question to me

Comment: Here's the link to the question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955498/layers-within-a-layer-in-caffe)