# Layers within a layer in Caffe

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, caffe, new-operator

I have a custom loss layer which I wrote, this layer applies `softmax` and `sigmoid` activation to part of the bottom[0] blob.

```
Ex: `bottom[0]` is of shape (say): `[20, 7, 7, 50]` (`NHWC` format)
I would like to apply `softmax` to `[20, 7, 7, 25]` (first 25 channels) and 
`sigmoid` to `[20, 7, 7, 1]` (just one channel) and the remaining 24 channels are taken in as it is.
```

How do I effectively allocate memory to the input blobs of these two `softmax` and `sigmoid` layers and also free this memory ?

Comment: This seems to solve the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of allocating data internally, you can simply use a [`"Slice"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/slice.html) layer externally and slice the input blob using caffe "off-the-shelf" layers:

```
layer {
  name: "slice"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "input_to_loss"
  top: "to_softmax"
  top: "to_sigmoid"
  top: "leftovers"
  slice_param { 
    axis: -1  # slice the last axis
    slice_point: 25
    slice_point: 26
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one more small doubt. Does slice_point include that axis in it's output or one minus the mentioned the slice axis ? I mean in the first slice_point, does that include upto axis 25 or upto axis 24 ?

Answer (score 0):

All the intermediate activations, along with the network's input and output blobs are managed by the net class and set up in the `Net<Dtype>::Init` function in `src/caffe/net.cpp`.

You don't need to allocate/deallocate the top and bottom blob memory from within the layer itself.

Comment: In that case I must send part of bottom[0] blob for softmax and part of bottom[0] blob for sigmoid, how do I accomplish this without creating new layers and having the blobs separate for these two layers ?